# Wrong reputation given on some SE sites

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

On these pages, it says that my TeX-LaTeX reputation is 113 (wrong):

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651/mzjn
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155793/mzjn

On these pages, it says that my TeX-LaTeX reputation is 128 (correct):

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16731/mzjn
- https://stackexchange.com/users/176760/mzjn?tab=accounts.

Update:

Soon after having posted this question, I noticed that the only TeX-LaTeX question that I have answered (in July 2012, giving me +27 in total) has been removed "for reasons of moderation". I have no idea what was wrong with it.

So it appears that neither of the scores mentioned is correct (I suppose it should be 101). People have suggested that the problem is related to caching (slow reputation update). But is that really the cause? The scores of 113 and 128 have been shown on my profile pages for several days.

Comment: Caching. Give it a couple of days...

Comment: @YannisRizos: Caching? The question that I got my rep from was answered more than a month ago. And now it has been removed.

Comment: @mzjn Removed? Well then you've also lost the rep from it, which means that the rep displayed in your SO profile is the correct one, and the rep on your Tex.SE is the cached one. Give it a couple of days...

Comment: @YannisRizos: How can the rep in the SO profile be correct? It should be 101 then not 113. Why hasn't all rep related to that question been removed?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, those profiles have said so for many days now. Now I have to ask: should it really be 113? It seems like it should be 101. Why am I not stripped of *all* rep (edit 2, upvote 10, accept 15) related to the single TeX-LaTeX question that I have answered?